# Convert Year/Month/Day to Day of Year in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm using the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module, i.e.:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print(today)
2009-03-06 13:24:58.857946
```

and I would like to compute the day of year that takes leap years into account. e.g. today (March 6, 2009) is the 65th day of 2009.

I see a two options:

1. Create a `number_of_days_in_month = [31, 28, ...]` array, decide if it's a leap year and manually sum up the days.
2. Use `datetime.timedelta` to make a guess & then binary search for the correct day of the year:

   ```
   >>> import datetime
   >>> YEAR = 2009
   >>> DAY_OF_YEAR = 62
   >>> d = datetime.date(YEAR, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(DAY_OF_YEAR - 1)
   ```

These both feel pretty clunky & I have a gut feeling that there's a more "Pythonic" way of calculating the day of the year. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 365, accepted):

Use [`datetime.timetuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetuple) to convert your `datetime` object to a [`time.struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time) object then get its [`tm_yday`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time) property:

```
from datetime import datetime
day_of_year = datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday  # returns 1 for January 1st
```

Comment: A very minor and arguably pedantic addition, but using `date.today()` rather than `datetime.now()` also works and emphasizes the nature of the operation a bit more.

Comment: **note:** this starts counting at 1

Comment: what if i want to do the reverse, I have the number lets say "26th day of the year 2020", and I want to have it converted into a date "26-01-2020"?

Comment: @Sankar then you google for that question and ask your own Stack Overflow question if you don't find anything.

Answer (score 66):

You could use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) with a [`%j` format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> today.strftime('%j')
'065'
```

but if you wish to do comparisons or calculations with this number, you would have to convert it to `int()` because `strftime()` returns a string. If that is the case, you are better off using [DzinX's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620305/convert-year-month-day-to-day-of-year-in-python/623312#623312) answer.

Comment: Using strftime is indirect, because it produces a string from a number: the timetuple.tm_yday member. Read the source. The produced string should be converted to a number before any calculations/comparisons, so why bother?

Comment: If one needed the day of year in a string, say for use in a file name, than strftime is a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 17):

[DZinX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/623312/40785) is a great answer for the question.  I found this question and used [DZinX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/623312/40785) while looking for the inverse function: convert dates with the julian day-of-year into the datetimes.

I found this to work:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('1936-077T13:14:15','%Y-%jT%H:%M:%S')

>>>> datetime.datetime(1936, 3, 17, 13, 14, 15)

datetime.datetime.strptime('1936-077T13:14:15','%Y-%jT%H:%M:%S').timetuple().tm_yday

>>>> 77
```

Or numerically:

```
import datetime
year,julian = [1936,77]
datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1)+datetime.timedelta(days=julian -1)

>>>> datetime.datetime(1936, 3, 17, 0, 0)
```

Or with fractional 1-based jdates popular in some domains:

```
jdate_frac = (datetime.datetime(1936, 3, 17, 13, 14, 15)-datetime.datetime(1936, 1, 1)).total_seconds()/86400+1
display(jdate_frac)

>>>> 77.5515625

year,julian = [1936,jdate_frac]
display(datetime.datetime(year, 1, 1)+datetime.timedelta(days=julian -1))

>>>> datetime.datetime(1936, 3, 17, 13, 14, 15)
```

I'm not sure of etiquette around here, but I thought a pointer to the inverse functionality might be useful for others like me.

Answer (score 12):

If you have reason to avoid the use of the `datetime` module, then these functions will work.

```
def is_leap_year(year):
    """ if year is a leap year return True
        else return False """
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return year % 400 == 0
    return year % 4 == 0

def doy(Y,M,D):
    """ given year, month, day return day of year
        Astronomical Algorithms, Jean Meeus, 2d ed, 1998, chap 7 """
    if is_leap_year(Y):
        K = 1
    else:
        K = 2
    N = int((275 * M) / 9.0) - K * int((M + 9) / 12.0) + D - 30
    return N

def ymd(Y,N):
    """ given year = Y and day of year = N, return year, month, day
        Astronomical Algorithms, Jean Meeus, 2d ed, 1998, chap 7 """    
    if is_leap_year(Y):
        K = 1
    else:
        K = 2
    M = int((9 * (K + N)) / 275.0 + 0.98)
    if N < 32:
        M = 1
    D = N - int((275 * M) / 9.0) + K * int((M + 9) / 12.0) + 30
    return Y, M, D
```

Comment: Useful when d,m,y are separately present!

Answer (score 9):

I want to present performance of different approaches, on Python 3.4, Linux x64. Excerpt from line profiler:

```
      Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
      ==============================================================
         (...)
         823      1508        11334      7.5     41.6          yday = int(period_end.strftime('%j'))
         824      1508         2492      1.7      9.1          yday = period_end.toordinal() - date(period_end.year, 1, 1).toordinal() + 1
         825      1508         1852      1.2      6.8          yday = (period_end - date(period_end.year, 1, 1)).days + 1
         826      1508         5078      3.4     18.6          yday = period_end.timetuple().tm_yday
         (...)
```

So most efficient is

```
yday = (period_end - date(period_end.year, 1, 1)).days + 1
```

Comment: How did you calculate the performance? I tried using time.time and those are my results:

    def f():
        (today - datetime.datetime(today.year, 1, 1)).days + 1
    
    start = time.time(); f(); print('Lapsed {}'.format(
            time.time() - start));
    Lapsed 5.221366882324219e-05
    def f():
        int(today.strftime('%j'));
        
    start = time.time(); f(); print('Lapsed {}'.format(
            time.time() - start));
    Lapsed 7.462501525878906e-05

Comment: Need a + 1 in the last line. Should be `yday = (period_end - date(period_end.year, 1, 1)).days + 1`.

Answer (score 5):

Just subtract january 1 from the date:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()
day_of_year = (today - datetime.datetime(today.year, 1, 1)).days + 1
```

Comment: d.toordinal() - date(d.year, 1, 1).toordinal() + 1 is more standard according to the documentation. It is equivalent to the accepted answer without producing the whole time tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You may simple use `dayofyear` attribute provided by "pandas" which in turn give you the day of the year for a particular year.
For e.g.

`data["day_of_year"] = data.Datetime.apply(lambda x:x.dayofyear)`

Comment: The question doesn't mention pandas, though.