# Python: Date to Day conversion

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, while-loop

Part of my midterm project is to convert a date (month and day) to the number day it is (1-366, including leap year), but I am unsure how to do this. I don't know how to make it work and I also don't know how to make it so you can only put in valid months (ie. Error, make sure to capitalize january.)

Below is what I have done so far.

```
#Months
January=0
February=31
March=60
April=91
May=121
June=152
July=182
August=213
September=244
October=274
November=305
December=335

#Title
print("Convert: Date to day and day to date.")

#user inputs a date
month=input("\nPick a Month (Make sure to capitalize the first letter): ")

day=int(input("Pick the day of the date you wish to input: "))
if day<0 or day>31:
    print("Error, no months have greater than 31 days or less than 1 day.")
```

Please help. I have been working on this for the past few days and still cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: If the user put 31 December how do you tell if it's the 365th or 366th day? Does the program only run on leap years?

Comment: Couple of tips - use a dictionary instead of your variables.. months = {'January': 0,.... }.. take your input and check if the value matches a key, if so, take the value from the dictionary and add the number of days to it.. this will get you a simple working solution.. now think about how you can improve that with extra validation

Comment: Can you use standard libraries such as `datetime`? If yes, I highly suggest you take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620305/convert-year-month-day-to-day-of-year-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very experienced in Python, so don't expect this to work like a charm and expect some room from improvement to be available. However, I tried this on my computer and it worked out fine. I will try to make this code more efficient and post that later.

I'm not sure if this code will work for your purpose, but I used what you gave me.

You also may want to prompt the user to enter a year in to determine whether the code is looking for dates to a year or leap year, but I'm not sure if you want that so I will leave it out for now. In this code, you can enter in the month however you want.

if you simply want to print the number of days into the year the entered date would be, then you may want to try something like the following (This program exits on incorrect answer as well):

```
#Months
#January=0
#February=31
#March=60
#April=91
#May=121
#June=152
#July=182
#August=213
#September=244
#October=274
#November=305
#December=335

monthvalue = -1

#Title
print("Convert: Date to day and day to date.")

#user inputs a date
month = input("\nPick a Month (Make sure to capitalize the first letter): ")
month = month.lower()
month = month[:1].capitalize() + month[1:]

if(month=="January"):
    monthvalue = 0

if(month=="February"):
    monthvalue = 31

if(month=="March"):
    monthvalue = 60

if(month=="April"):
    monthvalue = 91

if(month=="May"):
    monthvalue = 121

if(month=="June"):
    monthvalue = 152

if(month=="July"):
    monthvalue = 182

if(month=="August"):
    monthvalue = 213

if(month=="September"):
    monthvalue = 244

if(month=="October"):
    monthvalue = 274

if(month=="November"):
    monthvalue = 305

if(month=="December"):
    monthvalue = 335

if(monthvalue<0):
    print("Error, you have not entered a valid month.")
    xwdwa=input("\nPress any key to continue...")
    exit(0)

day=int(input("Pick the day of the date you wish to input: "))
if day<1 or day>31:
    print("Error, no months have greater than 31 days or less than 1 day.")

total = monthvalue + day

print("Your date is ", total, " days into a leap year.")
exitvar = input("Press any key to continue.")
```

Comment: If anyone wants to edit this and make it more efficient and make it able to determine if a leap year is present or not, go for it. It would be greatly appreciated. There also may be an issue with the day determination...

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
_DAYS_IN_MONTH = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

def _is_leap(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

def _days_in_month(year, month):
    if month == 2 and _is_leap(year):
        return 29
    return _DAYS_IN_MONTH[month]

def days(year, month, day):
    return sum([_days_in_month(year, m) for m in range(0, month)]) + day

d = days(1992, 4, 14)
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
132
```

This is easily done by creating a few simple functions:

1. Create a `list` of each number of days in a month.
2. Create a function to see whether it is leap year or not.
3. Create a function that leverages the `is_leapyear` function that we have just made in order to tell you the number of days on that month in a leap year or normal year.
4. Create the function that will tell us the number of days that have gone by up until that month and day. It works by:

   - Creating a list comprehension that returns a list of each of the days up until that month.
   - Adds the number of days that have gone by in that month to the sum of all the days in the months prior.

Answer (score 1):

```
_DAYS_IN_MONTH = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

def _is_leap(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

def _days_in_month(year, month):
    if month == 2 and _is_leap(year):
        return 29
    return _DAYS_IN_MONTH[month]

def days(year, month, day):
    return sum([_days_in_month(year, m) for m in range(0, month)]) + day

d = days(1992, 4, 14)
print(d)
```

Shouldn't month == 1 instead of month == 2 since the range() starts at 0, 0 being January and 1 being February?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what this program is producing and I don't see where months are being used. However, if your question is how to capitalize first letter of user input or even ensure to have it if your program is expecting it, try:

```
month = raw_input("\nPick a Month (Make sure to capitalize the first letter): ")
month = month[:1].capitalize() + month[1:]
```

Month's first letter will be capitalize.