# Python:How to scatterplot many years of data into one year, based on the date

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, scatter-plot

I have a csv file that contains 13 years of data about temperature on each day. Now I need to scatter plot these 13 years of data. I would like the x axis to be only one year of dates(366 days) so that the value on each date can be shown on the same date, without the year. For example, the temperature on August1st(87F) can be shown on the same y axis, no matter which year it is in. How does that work?
This is what the data looks like: besides 1980, there are other years like 1981 that also has August 1st. I want their temperature to be on the same y-axis
[image]

Comment: you could convert you dates to day of year http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620305/convert-year-month-day-to-day-of-year-in-python

Answer (score 1):

As you want a scatter plot, one approach would be to simply use the same year from all of your data and to then plot all entries in the range of the days for say 2016 (which is a leap year).

To get the start range to work for a particular day, use the day of the year to determine a split point.

This could be done as follows:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot, dates
from datetime import datetime
import itertools
data = [
    ["STATION", "DATE", "TMAX", "TMIN"],
    ["X", "19800801", "87", "66"],
    ["X", "19800801", "87", "72"],
    ["X", "19800802", "88", "64"],
    ["X", "19800802", "86", "68"],
    ["X", "19800803", "80", "67"],
    ["X", "19800804", "89", "63"],
    ["X", "19800804", "88", "68"],
    ["X", "19800805", "89", "72"],
    ["X", "19800805", "88", "67"],
    ["X", "19800806", "85", "66"],

    # Some random data for 1984 (a leap year)
    ["X", "19840101", "77", "66"],
    ["X", "19840229", "77", "72"],
    ["X", "19840302", "78", "64"],
    ["X", "19840402", "76", "68"],
    ["X", "19840503", "73", "67"],
    ["X", "19840604", "79", "63"],
    ["X", "19840704", "78", "68"],
    ["X", "19840805", "79", "72"],
    ["X", "19840805", "78", "67"],
    ["X", "19841206", "75", "66"]]

# Date range to map data onto
d1 = datetime(year=2015, month=9, day=30)
d365 = datetime(year=2016, month=9, day=29)

yday = d1.timetuple().tm_yday   # Start day of year
pyplot.xlim(dates.date2num(d1), dates.date2num(d365))

axis_lookup = {}

# Spread data over the selected range
for s, d, tmax, tmin in data[1:]:
    dt = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y%m%d')
    year = int(dt.year)
    print(year)
    if dt.timetuple().tm_yday <  yday:
        dt = dt.replace(year=d365.year)
    else:
        dt = dt.replace(year=d1.year)

    axis_lookup[year] = axis_lookup.get(year,{'x':[],'y':[]})
    axis_lookup[year]['x'].append(dt)
    axis_lookup[year]['y'].append(tmax)


ax = pyplot.gca()
    # Convert to maplotlib format
hfmt = dates.DateFormatter('%m')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator())
colors = itertools.cycle(["r", "b", "g"])


pyplot.xlabel('Month')
pyplot.ylabel('Temperature')

for year,axes in axis_lookup.items():
    xaxis = dates.date2num(axes['x'])
    pyplot.scatter(xaxis, axes['y'],color=next(colors), label=year,)
pyplot.tight_layout()
pyplot.legend()
pyplot.show()
```

Giving you an output as:

[image: sample output]

Comment: Hi: when I did something like this: [datetime.strptime(d[4:], '%m%d') for s, d, tmax, tmin in data[1:]], it keeps giving me error: day out of range for month. Why does that happen? How should I avoid that?

Comment: I think it's because year 1900 does not have the leap day in Feb, but some years in my data has Feb.29th. So is there any other way I can include that extra day in my x axis to make it 366 days instead of 365 days? Thanks!

Comment: Well spotted, in that case, keep the year but then replace it with a leap year e.g. 2016. I have updated the script.

Comment: Wow that does solve the problem! I have another question, can I modify my xaxis so that the first day is September 30th, instead of January 1st?

Comment: You need to change `d1` and `d365` and then use the day of the year to decide which year to map onto e.g. 2015 or 2016. I have updated the script.

Answer (score 0):

if you read in the dates as datetime using strptime. you could convert you dates to day of year

[Convert Year/Month/Day to Day of Year in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620305/convert-year-month-day-to-day-of-year-in-python)

```
def day_of_year(date_string):
  return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y%m%d').timetuple().tm_yday

date_string = '19800801'

day_of_year(date_string)

>>> 214
```

Comment: Wow that helps a lot. I have another question. How do we set the first day to Sep 30th, instead of the default Jan 1st?