# Day number of a quarter for a given date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have create a dataframe of dates as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

timespan = 366
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=timespan).tolist()})
```

I'm struggling to identify the day number in a quarter.  For example

```
date          expected_value
2017-01-01       1           # First day in Q1
2017-01-02       2           # Second day in Q1
2017-02-01      32           # 32nd day in Q1
2017-04-01       1           # First day in Q2
```

May I have your suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at Alexander's answer. I think that's the best solution so far.

Comment: Jedi's solution is faster than Alexander's one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58333066/940974

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of way is by creating a new df based on dates and quarter cumcount then map the values to the real df i.e

```
timespan = 5000
ndf = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=timespan).tolist()})
ndf['q'] = ndf['Date'].dt.to_period('Q')
ndf['new'] = ndf.groupby('q').cumcount()+1
maps = dict(zip(ndf['Date'].dt.date, ndf['new'].values.tolist()))
```

Map the values

```
df['expected'] = df.Date.dt.date.map(maps)
```

Output:

```
                       Date  expected
0 2017-09-12 09:42:14.324492        74
1 2017-09-13 09:42:14.324492        75
2 2017-09-14 09:42:14.324492        76
3 2017-09-15 09:42:14.324492        77
4 2017-09-16 09:42:14.324492        78
.
.
143 2018-02-02 09:42:14.324492        33
.
.
201 2018-04-01 09:42:14.324492         1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you Bharath.  Your solution works.  

However, I'm just wondering what if my first row in df is not the first of Jan. 
 I may need to do something with groupby.  Otherwise, the expected results are incorrect until the next quarter come.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> df.assign(
        days_in_qurater=[(date - ts.start_time).days + 1 
                         for date, ts in zip(df['Date'], 
                                             pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'], freq='Q'))])
          Date  days_in_qurater
0   2017-01-01                1
1   2017-01-02                2
2   2017-01-03                3
...
363 2017-12-30               91
364 2017-12-31               92
365 2018-01-01                1
```

Comment: This is awesome. Really nice

Answer (score 4):

This is around 250x faster than [Alexander's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46168029/5752314):

```
df['day_qtr']=(df.Date - pd.PeriodIndex(df.Date,freq='Q').start_time).dt.days + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

start with:

```
day_of_year = datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday
```

from 
[Convert Year/Month/Day to Day of Year in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620305/convert-year-month-day-to-day-of-year-in-python)

you can get 1st day of each quarter that way and bracket / subtract the value of the first day to get the day of the quarter

Comment: In pandas if you want the day of the year then you can use .dt accessor with series. i.e  `df.Date.dt.dayofyear` .