# Creating a column to count days in quarter

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, python-datetime

I have data frame of dates, and I need to count the "days into current quarter" for each date. For example --April 4, 2022 is the 4th day of the quarter. And May 4 is the 34th day of the quarter.

In the data frame, I already added `df['dates'].dt.is_quarter_start` to return True at the start of a new quarter, and False for every other day. My goal is to add another column called `day_of_quarter` to start with `1` at each quarter-begin and count up every day until the next quarter.

What do I need to do to create the day_of_quarter column?

Sample data:

```
[dates, is_quarter_begin],

 [Timestamp('2003-06-29 00:00:00'), False],

 [Timestamp('2003-06-30 00:00:00'), False],

 [Timestamp('2003-07-01 00:00:00'), True],

 [Timestamp('2003-07-02 00:00:00'), False],
```

Comment: The solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167550/day-number-of-a-quarter-for-a-given-date-in-pandas/58333066#58333066

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Day number of a quarter for a given date in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167550/day-number-of-a-quarter-for-a-given-date-in-pandas)