# Is there any python Timestamp API to calculate day of year, month of year and week of year

Tags: python, timestamp

while working with timestamps in python i want to calculate

DayofYear
MonthofYear
WeekofYear

using timestamp object.

Well i see there is one available 
TimestampObject.dayofyear

I need to know if i can do

TimestampObject.weekofyear
TimestampObject.monthofyear

Comment: Have you checked out the documentation?

Comment: Have a look at the datetime module and maybe here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620305/convert-year-month-day-to-day-of-year-in-python to get some ideas

Comment: Did you do some research before posting a question? Share your approach so that it can be corrected.

Comment: Thanks @voiDnyx but i am more interested in timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Actually i found the answer thanks anyways.

i can use **pd.Timestamp** for all the calculations

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html