# Need help in finding the day of given (year,month,date) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def isYearLeap(year):   # Leap year formula

    if year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0 :     
        return True 
    elif year % 400 == 0 :
        return True
    else :
        return False
    
            
testData = [1900, 2000, 2016, 1987]         # Test Data as reference

testResults = [False, True, True, False]

for i in range(len(testData)):

    yr = testData[i]
    print(yr,"->",end="")
    result = isYearLeap(yr)
    if result == testResults[i]:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("Failed")

def daysInMonth(year, month): # Finding out days in months in common & leap year

    days = 0
    mo31 = [1,3,7,5,8,10,12]
    if year % 4 == 0 :              
        days = 1
        if year % 100 == 0 :
            days = 0
        if year % 400 == 0 :
            days = 1
    if month == 2 :
        return 28 + days
    if month in mo31 :
        return 31
    return 30

testYears = [1900, 2000, 2016, 1987] # Test Data as reference 

testMonths = [2, 2, 1, 11]
testResults = [28, 29, 31, 30]

for i in range(len(testYears)):

    yr = testYears[i]
    mo = testMonths[i]
    print(yr, mo, "->", end="")
    result = daysInMonth(yr, mo)
    if result == testResults[i]:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("Failed")
        
def dayOfYear(year, month, day):

    doy = ["Sat","Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri"] # Days of week
    monthvalue = [1,4,4,0,2,5,0,3,6,1,4,6]        # Months value zellers rule
    century = [1700,1800,1900,2000]      # Zellers rule 
    value = [4,2,0,6]   # Zellers rule
    rem = 0     # Remainder Variable
    r = []      # Empty List to compare remainder and to a doy
    y = str(year)   # Converting year into string
    y = int(y[2:4]) # Taking last two digits of string & if used return the function ends 
    y = int(year)   # here returning last two digits 
    m = int(month)
    d = int(day)
    mo = [] # Empty list for comparing month with monthly values
    dd = 0   
    if dd == 0 :
        for i in range(len(monthvalue)) :
            mo.append(i)    # Creating mo list
            if m in mo:
                mo[i] == monthvalue[i]
        dd = y // 4 + d + m 
    if m >= 2 :                  
            dd -= 1
            dd += y
    for i in range(len(value)) :
        if y in century :
            y = century[i] == value[i]
            dd += y
            
    rem = dd % 7
    for i in range(len(doy)) :
        r.append(i) # Creating r list
        if rem in r :
            rem = r[i] == doy[i]
    print(rem)
        
    
        
print(dayOfYear(2000, 12, 31)) # Giving output False  "\n None
```

Comment: What is the question? Please read about [ask] and how to create a [mre]

Comment: Duplicate: [Convert Year/Month/Day to Day of Year in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620305/convert-year-month-day-to-day-of-year-in-python)

Comment: Do I have to assume this is an exercise and you are not allowing `import datetime`,  `date = datetime.datetime(2000, 12, 31)` and `date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %A")`, which will return: `12/31/2000, Sunday`?

Comment: It's a lab work from netacad cisco academy python course and i am having trouble with the function " def dayOfYear(year, month, day): " where , " Your task is to write and test a function which takes three arguments (a year, a month, and a day of the month) and returns the corresponding day of the year, or returns None if any of the arguments is invalid. The two functions above works totally fine and those are from previous labs but some how was needed in this lab section . It requires these two functions to be defined before the " def dayOfYear(year, month, day): " function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains a lot of illogical statements and redundancies, that make the code hard to read/understand.
I'd recommend first looking into a few style guides or more basic python tutorials.

Some examples:

```
y = str(year)   # Converting year into string
y = int(y[2:4]) # Taking last two digits of string & if used return the function ends 
y = int(year)   # here returning last two digits
```

While the first two statements don't have any effect, their comments makes me think you forgot about two lines of code in between.

```
dd = 0   
if dd == 0 :
    ...
```

That if check will never evaluate to false, so it's redundant

```
for i in range(len(monthvalue)) :
  mo.append(i)    # Creating mo list
  if m in mo:
     mo[i] == monthvalue[i]
```

The mo variable/list is never used again

Please check your program flow and report back

Comment: Concerning the outputs:
False is from `rem = r[i] == doy[i]` where you'll always eventually assign `some number == some weekday` to rem. Since you only print it and don't return it, the function dayOfYear will return None, which you print at the end of your function

Comment: Thank you so much when i return doy[i] at the end it's returning the day i just need to find out some calculations error in between because i need to take last two digits of the year to make the calculations right , as you said y = str(year) & the next two lines don't have any effect i do know this because when i use return int(y[2:4]) the function ends there & it only shows the last two digits of the year when executed  , the rest of the function is ignored .

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this as a lab in the netacad cisco python course.
You were tasked with creating an is_year_leap() function in LAB 4.3.1.6, a days_in_month() function in LAB 4.3.1.7, and a day_of_year() function in LAB 4.3.1.8. The functions have one, two, three parameters respectively. Please see below code. Note that I excluded a code to return None if any of the arguments are invalid. I would like you to add that on your own as learning.

```
# from LAB 4.3.1.6
def is_year_leap(year):
    if year % 4 == 0:  # leap year occur every 4 years & is divisible by 4
        return True
    else:
        return False


# from LAB 4.3.1.7
def days_in_month(year, month):
    # Create list with month days for each month as advised in the LAB
    month_days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if is_year_leap(year):
        month_days[1] = 29  # 29 days for February on a leap year.
    return month_days[month - 1]  # month 1 corresponds with index 0 & so on.


# for LAB 4.3.1.8
def day_of_year(year, month, day):
    total = 0  # initializing the total variable to add results
    # create loop to add only days in the months before the month in the input/test data
    for i in range(1, month):
        result = days_in_month(year, i)
        total += result
    day_num = total + day  # add the value of the day argument to get day of the year
    return day_num


# test data
print(day_of_year(2000, 12, 31))
print(day_of_year(1999, 12, 31))
print(day_of_year(2021, 7, 29))
```

Answer (score 0):

A point to note is the occurrence of days above the number of days of months.

```py
def is_year_leap(year):
    return year % 4 == 0 and not year % 100 == 0 or year % 400 == 0


def days_in_month(year, month):
    days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if is_year_leap(year):
        days[1] = 29
    return days[month - 1]


def day_of_year(year, month, day):
    if day <= days_in_month(year, month):
        count = 0
        for yr in range(1, month):
            count += days_in_month(year, yr)
        return count + day
```

Comment: Hey navigos, please have a read of [how to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) so your code is more easily understood

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The leap year should fulfil all its conditions for getting the day of the year.

- if the year is divisible by 400 then is_leap_year,
- else if the year is divisible by 100 then not_leap_year
- else if the year is divisible by 4 then is_leap_year
- else not_leap_year

The number of days should also be checked whether it exceeds the day in the month.

```
#Check for leap year
def is_year_leap(year):
    if year%400==0 or (year%100 != 0 and year%4==0):
        return True
    else:
        return False

#Check for number of days in month
def days_in_month(year, month):
    month31=[1,3,5,7,8,10,12]
    if month in month31:
        return 31
    elif(month == 2):
        if(is_year_leap(year)):
            return 29
        else:
            return 28
    else:
        return 30


#Check for corresponding day of the year
def day_of_year(year, month, day):
    total = 0
    if day <= days_in_month(year, month):
        total = day
        for i in range(month-1):
            total += days_in_month(year, i)
        return total
    else:
        return "Your month doesn't have that many days."


print(day_of_year(2000, 12, 31))
print(day_of_year(2001, 12, 31))
print(day_of_year(2008, 12, 31))
print(day_of_year(2000, 11, 31))
```