# IQ command in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

I wanted to make fun iq command which sends a random iq for a member which changes every 24 hours

```
@client.command()
async def iq(ctx):
    iq = random.randint(0,200)
    print(iq)
    await ctx.send(f'IQ of {ctx.author.name} is ' + str(iq) + ' today')
```

This is my this works but it keep changing, I wanted to know if there is a option so the iq doesn't change everytime the member type `iq`  and stay constant per member and be constent for 24 hours and then change again to a random number?

Comment: If you mean generate once randomly for each user and repeat it in future invocations, you'll have to use a dictionary or similar data structure. To make it persistent across reboots use json or csv to save to file and load when bot starts. Each section has already been separately asked and should be easily googelable.

Comment: @Nevus [I tried this](https://i.imgur.com/1Od8g40.png) on python 2.7, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10 on windows. everyone except the 2.7 were the same. I also tried on ubuntu on 3.8 and it was same too. OP is not gonna be using discord.py on python 2.7 :)

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using the user's id as a [seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) using the [`random.seed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) method

```py
@client.command()
async def iq(ctx):
    random.seed(ctx.author.id)
    iq = random.randint(0,200)
    print(iq)
    await ctx.send(f'IQ of {ctx.author.name} is ' + str(iq) + ' today')
```

Comment: Now that I think about it even modulus of user.id and 200 would be kinda random because user id is random from user's perspective. :)

Comment: Thanks your code worked but I want to know that can I make this seed to be regenerated in a day at 0000 hours?

Comment: @AarshRaghuvanshi I guess you can use the user's id and [the current date of the year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/623312/13123877) as a combination for the seed. Although this will mean the user would get the same iq in the same day each year

Comment: I was thinking like to use asyncio to set a timestamp for the iq for 24 hours but I am confused what the code should be