# Check if date is between two dates without year included

Tags: python, datetime

I have a datetime date in the format yyyy-mm-dd and I want to check if the date entered falls between for example May 15th and May 25th without including any year value.

```
tripDate_str = str(input("Please enter the trip start date in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD "))

import datetime
tripDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(tripDate_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Please consider that the idea of not coping with the year runs into severe trouble with switch years if you want for example to set the range begin on 29-th February and the range end on 1-st March. Not every year does it make sense ...

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess the simplest approach is to use the month and day date class attributes

```
import datetime
tripDate = datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-05-15', "%Y-%m-%d")

start = datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-05-10', "%Y-%m-%d")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime('2022-05-20', "%Y-%m-%d")

if tripDate.month >= start.month and tripDate.month <= end.month and tripDate.day >= start.day and tripDate.day <= end.day:
    print('Date in range')
else:
    print('Date not in range')
```

Comment: Check out what your code will give in case of e,g. a range from  2022-04-29 to 2022-05-03 and a tripDate of 2022-05-01 to see that the code doesn't work as expected for every possible case without more complex conditions to check what you can avoid using day of year instead.

Answer (score 0):

> ... check if the date entered falls between for example May 15th and May 25th without including any year value

Did you know you can compare tuples?

When you "remove" the year from a date, you are left with a `(month, day)` tuple, that can be directly used in a comparison like `begin < now < end`.

```py
def in_timeframe(begin, end, the_date):
    begin_ = begin.month, begin.day
    end_ = end.month, end.day
    the_date_ = the_date.month, the_date.day

    if begin_ > end_:
        # `begin` larger than `end` means the timeframe is over the year boundary
        return begin_ <= the_date_ <= (12, 31) or (1, 1) <= the_date_ <= end_
    else:
        return begin_ <= the_date_ <= end_

# define the boundaries of your date-range
# year does not matter: 1972 is the first leapyear after epoch
begin = date(1972, 12, 21)
end = date(1972, 3, 20)

# check if today is still technically winter...
in_timeframe(begin, end, date(2024, 3, 8))
# True
```

- As `the_date` argument `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.date` is acceptable.
- This does not care about leapyears or calendars at all. It's just working with tuples of two integers.
- You could of course change the function to have the boundaries already be defined as tuples, instead of using 1972 as a placeholder.
- Also, adapt the comparison to use `<=` or `<` as you need.
- Keep in mind, that a boundary of larger than a year is not possible; the code has no concept of year; there is nothing smaller than `(1, 1)` or bigger than `(12, 31)`.

Answer (score -1):

There are many options to get the day of the year from a date. Use a search engine with keywords `python day of year` to find out which or just look [here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620305/convert-year-month-day-to-day-of-year-in-python) ("Convert Year/Month/Day to Day of Year in Python"). The code below is using for this purpose `dateObject.timetuple().tm_yday`:

```
tripDate_str = str(input("Please enter the trip start date in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD "))
# tripDate_str = "2022-05-18"
## Finding day of year
from datetime import date
tripDate = date(*map(int, tripDate_str.split('-')))
tripDate_dayOfYear = tripDate.timetuple().tm_yday
print("Day of year: ", tripDate_dayOfYear,  type(tripDate_dayOfYear))
dateRangeBeg_dayOfYear = date(tripDate.year, 5, 15).timetuple().tm_yday
dateRangeEnd_dayOfYear = date(tripDate.year, 5, 25).timetuple().tm_yday
if dateRangeBeg_dayOfYear <= tripDate_dayOfYear <= dateRangeEnd_dayOfYear:
    print("tripDate falls into range", dateRangeBeg_dayOfYear, dateRangeEnd_dayOfYear)
else:
    print("tripDate is outside range", dateRangeBeg_dayOfYear, dateRangeEnd_dayOfYear)
```

To avoid a problem with leap years `tripDate.year` is used in setting the values of `dateRangeBeg_dayOfYear` and `dateRangeEnd_dayOfYear`.