# What does datetime.now().strftime("%j") do?

Tags: python, datetime

To get the current year using the datetime module, you can use `datetime.now().strftime("%Y")`, which returns `2023` as expected.

However, I found that another argument, `%j` can be passed instead of `%Y`. Doing this returns `309`.

What does `%j` do?

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.now().strftime("%Y")) #Returns current year (2023)
print(datetime.now().strftime("%j")) #Returns 309
```

Comment: %j returns the current day of the year. 309th day of the year, which is November 5th

Comment: You'll find the documentation useful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: Python is [well documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes), always ask google before asking StackOverflow

Comment: Day of the year as a zero-padded decimal number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Year/Month/Day to Day of Year in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620305/convert-year-month-day-to-day-of-year-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's day of the year. For example, Jan 1 is the 1st day of the year etc.

```py
from datetime import datetime

datetime(2023,1,1).strftime('%j')     # '001'

datetime(2023,12,30).strftime('%j')   # '364'

datetime(2024,12,31).strftime('%j')   # '366'
```